# fetch value of row base on value of another row in csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, read.csv

consider we have a data.csv file

| sentiment | content |
| --- | --- |
| anger | this content about angry |
| happy | this is happy content |
| anger | this about angry |
| sadness | this is sad content content |

I want to get all rows of column 'content' where the value of column 'sentiment' row value is 'anger'

the angry content in a list is

[this content about angry, this about angry]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df[df['sentiment'] == 'anger']]
```

Comment: And to get the output he was asking for, you could make it `df[df['sentiment'] == 'anger']]['content'].values.tolist()`